# How to add Firebase crash analytics in singleton class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Hi I am trying to integrate Firebase crash analytics in one singleton class and that class able to fire all crashes which are happening at remaining classes is this possible

please, someone, help to do this requirement....

```
FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("My first Android non-fatal error"));
```

Comment: I dont' get it, you want to notify the errors to other classes? Something like EventBus? https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: Make a generic class which will report crashes, and pass exceptions to this class for reporting!

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#create_your_first_error):

> Firebase Crash Reporting automatically generates reports for fatal errors (or uncaught exceptions).

So you don't need to do anything specific: uncaught exceptions are automatically reported to Firebase.